# Происхождение слов "калькулятор" и "сколько"

Tags: этимология

Откуда пришло в русский язык и как было образовано слово «калькулятор»? Имеет ли оно хоть какую то связь с исконным словом «сколько» (будет дважды два)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в википедии [кое что:](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

Латинское слово calculator «счётчик, счетовод» происходит от глагола calculo «считаю, подсчитываю», который, в свою очередь, происходит от слова calculus «камешек» (камешки использовались для счёта); calculus же является уменьшительным от calx «известь».

В Советском Союзе для обозначения малогабаритного вычислительного устройства использовался термин «микрокалькулятор», впервые применённый в 1974 году для микрокалькулятора «Электроника Б3-04». Просто «калькуляторами» называли большие по размеру настольные вычислительные устройства. И настольные, и микрокалькуляторы официально назывались «ЭКВМ — электронные клавишные вычислительные машины». Впоследствии, после отмирания «больших» калькуляторов, термины «калькулятор» (в рассматриваемом смысле) и «микрокалькулятор» стали синонимами.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "сколько" — собственно русское производное с приставкой *съ-* и суффиксом *-ко* от праслав. **коль*, **коли*, восходящих к и.-е. **kwe-l-*: **kwo-l-*, расширенной основе от местоимения **kwe-*: **kwo-*: **kwu-*.
Слово "калькулятор" заимствовано из нем. *Kalkulator*, восходящего к лат. *calculator* 'счетчик' от *calculare* 'считать, подсчитывать'. *Calculare*, в свою очередь, восходит к *calculus* 'камешек (галька), используемый для счета', которое является [диминутивом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2) *calx* (генетив *calcis*) 'известняк, маленький камень'; *calx* восходит к греч. *khalix* 'маленькая галька', и.-е. основа которого имеет значение 'разбивать, раскалывать'.

В общем, никак не связаны эти слова.

Источники:
http://www.etymonline.com/
"Этимологический словарь современного русского языка" Шапошникова